# Not found sigset.h on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am trying to prepare development environment as Docker container for pretty old project written in C.

I chose Ubuntu 20.04, previously it was CentOS 6.5 - no conflict between these two OSs.

Compiler: GCC 10

Unfortunately, file called "sigset.h" cannot be found - this file is marked as obselete.

Any idea how to fix it without interfering with the code?

Comment: sigset.h was a legacy interface and is no longer available in Ubuntu 20.04 There seems to be some attempt to manually fetch it here (https://askubuntu.com/a/1321262) noting that is is part of uusr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits . It might work but your easiest bet is to use an Ubuntu 18 or older image.

Comment: I think you can just use `signal.h` instead of `sigset.h`.  You'll probably also need the feature-test macro specified in `man sigset`. If you can't edit the source files, you could create your own `sigset.h`, which just has `#include <signal.h>`, and put it somewhere the compiler looks for include files.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 also doesn't include these files, Ubuntu 16.04 does.

Comment: Symbolic link of signal.h also did not solve my problem as more and more missing files appeared